# Resetting index and setting a new index creates multi-level column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following code:

```
df = pageview_df[['student_id', 'page_id']].groupby('student_id').agg('count')
df.head(3)
```

Which generates the following dataframe:

```
              page_id
student_id
         1    22
         2    34
         3    30
```

Then, as an attempt to have only single layer of columns, I reset the index this:

```
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df.head(3)
```

Resulting in this dataframe:

```
   student_id    page_id
0           1    22
1           2    34
2           3    30
```

But, then I want to get rid of the new automatically generated index, and use `student_id` as the new index:

```
df = df.set_index('student_id')
df.head(3)
```

But, then this code gives me what I originally have:

```
              page_id
student_id
         1    22
         2    34
         3    30
```

Can someone explain me why it works this way? How can I resolve this issue? I want to obtain this dataframe:

```
student_id    page_id
         1    22
         2    34
         3    30
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining exactly what your expected output is?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ yes, I did, thanks!

Comment: Okay, this is a  `__repr__` issue, and is a consequence of how dataframes are designed to display when printed in a terminal. I doubt that's something you can change.

Comment: So, short answer is, no. Not possible. But you can work around this with `print(df.reset_index().to_string(index=False))`